# Alternate way of using __init_subclass__ in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

1-`BaseClass.py`--->

```
class BaseClass:

    request_mapper = {}
    def __init_subclass__(cls, data_validation_case_name=None, **kwargs):
        #super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        if data_validation_case_name is None:
            data_validation_case_name = cls.__name__
            print("data_validation_case_name=[{}]".format(data_validation_case_name))
        print("Type of cls is =[{}]".format(type(cls)))
        cls.request_mapper[data_validation_case_name] = cls

    @classmethod
    def get_class_for_data_validation_case_name(cls, data_validation_case_name):
        if data_validation_case_name in cls.request_mapper:
            return cls.request_mapper[data_validation_case_name]
        else:
            raise NotImplementedError
```

2-`ChildClass.py`---->

```
from BaseClass import BaseClass

class count_check(BaseClass):
    @classmethod
    def execute(cls,self):
        print('count_check_execute')
        return

class duplicate_check(BaseClass):
    def execute(self):
        print('duplicate_check_execute')
        return
```

3-`call_main.py`--->

```
import BaseClass
from ChildClass import *

list_of_cases=['count_check','duplicate_check']

if __name__ == "__main__":

   for validation_case_name in list_of_cases:
      child_validation_class = BaseClass.get_class_for_data_validation_case_name(validation_case_name)
      child_validation_class.execute(child_validation_class)
```

4- `__init__.py`--->

I have four files as a package and I am running the call_main.py. When I run this with python 3.7 it gives me an output but not with python 2.7 since `__init_subclass__()` is not being supported in python 2.

Is there an alternate way we can do similar thing in python 2

Comment: You can use a custom metaclass, as `__init_subclass__` was introduced as a cleaner alternative. I would recommend moving to Python 3, if at all feasible, rather than going the metaclass route.

Comment: Thanks @chepner for your comments. I do have a compulsion to run this in python 2. Can you also provide a small sample code for such custom metaclass where I can implement similar thing.